# POST role when updating records in the database using the conservation form

Tags: python, django

please explain the following

documentation is an example of saving the form in the database:

```
>>> from myapp.models import Article
>>> from myapp.forms import ArticleForm

#1
# Create a form instance from POST data.
>>> f = ArticleForm(request.POST)
# Save a new Article object from the form's data.
>>> new_article = f.save()

#2
# Create a form to edit an existing Article, but use
# POST data to populate the form.
>>> a = Article.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> f = ArticleForm(request.POST, instance=a)
>>> f.save()
```

here in the first case there is add a new record to the database

in the second case is to update the existing record in the database

in both cases transmitted to POST dictionary that was added or updated. but the latter is transmitted dictionary 'a' through a keyword argument instance (but is used to update the record 'a', and not POST)

question. why in the second case is transferred dictionary POST?

Comment: Not really sure what's being asked here. The second example updates instance `a` with data `request.POST`. The first example creates a new instance with data `request.POST`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases you actually pass the `request.POST` dictionary as a single argument to the form's `__init__` method. That way the form can differentiate the actual post data and other arguments. The `request.POST` dictionary is in its completeness saved in the `data` attribute. Later on, in the `is_valid` method, the keys and values in the dictionary are checked against the form's fields and used to validate the form and populate the `cleaned_data` attribute.